# Not being able to set a value to a combobox

Tags: combobox, vb6

This is an old Vb6 application I'm working on - and I'm having somewhat of a hard time of setting a value to a combobox.

I first load the data to combobox - mind you - I'm only setting the text values in the combobox, no ID's. Here's what the code looks like...

```
Dim z As Integer
Dim a As Integer

oCombobox.Clear
oCombobox.AddItem "", 0

Call GetValuesForCbo

Do While Rs.EOF = False
    z = z + 1
    oCombobox.AddItem "", z

    For a = 0 To oCombobox.ColumnCount - 1
        oCombobox.List(z, a) = Rs.Fields(a).Value
    Next

    Rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

So what happens is I have this function where I pass a ComboxName aka oCombobox. In CallValuesForCBO I query the database to get the values.

```
The values are definitely there because I don't get an error when i do this...

m_stringValue = 'Hello' <--this is one of the values I load into combobox
cboName.Value = m_stringValue <-- while this does not throw an error, it does not display any value in the cbo
```

Comment: do you know VB's Object Explorer? Try to explore the ComboBox Class Members

Comment: @deblocker not sure if i've used it. I'm trying to make this function work - it works perfectly fine in loading the combobox for when i want to select it but won't do it when I set the value. In properties the columns is set to 1. What can be wrong?

Comment: Negative comment ? Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VB.ComboBox` doesn't have `ColumnCount` property.

Comment: It does, this is the combobox 2.0 or SScombobox - whatever the proper name

Comment: ...the creator of the VS6 Installer? Upvote your partecipation!